# Instantiating an HttpClient object in abstract class

Tags: angular

I am currently creating an abstract class that every service can inherit from. I try to instantiate the HttpClient in the abstract class but an argument is needed. Which one (what type, ...)?

I don't want to repeat it in constructor of inherited classes. That's why I am trying to do so.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export abstract class GenericService<T> {
  //... code ...

  constructor() {
    this._http = new HttpClient(); // Argument needed ?
  }

  //... code ...
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't new it up yourself *anywhere*, that's the whole point of Angular's DI system: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Do you find anything in the docs where the HttpClient is newed up? No. That's because you get it via constructor injection.

Comment: you need inject it (in the constructor or using Injector)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export abstract class GenericService<T> {
  //... code ...

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  //... code ...
}
```

Comment: But then I have to do for all inherited classes `constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {super(_http);}`. This is what I wanted to avoid; seems not possible easily.